# Strange tiling pattern

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Here is a simple pentagonal shape:

[image]

Using copies of this shape it seems that you can tile the plane, without even needing to flip over the tile.

[image]

But can you really?

Comment: I think this tiling was first discovered by Marjorie Rice, and she made a nice artwork version of it which can be seen [on her website](https://sites.google.com/site/intriguingtessellations/home/tessellations/shell). This tiling has also been found by others, such as [Livio Zucca](https://www.iread.it/lz/pagesp/nc180h.html). As my question implies, there is something wrong with it.

Comment: It's rather fascinating how much this *almost* works.

Comment: @RobWatts: Yes, so it is not too surprising that people didn't notice the problem. I only took a closer look at this tiling after systematic computer search for tilings didn't find this one when I thought it should have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's annotate the picture to make it easier to identify matching corners:

[image]

> By vile abuse of notation let A,B,C,D,E denote the angles at the five corners.
>  Inspecting the tiling we can read off:
>  
>  360 = B+E+B+E = B+E+C+C = A+A+B = E+D+D
>  
>  It follows
>  
>  B+E = 180°
>  
>  C = 90°
>  
>  A = E+B/2 = C+E/2
>  
>  D = B+E/2 = C+B/2

> Checking incident edges yields:
>  
>  AB = CD = AE = BC = DE
>  
>  In other words the pentagon is equilateral. In particular, triangle AED is isosceles and the angle <DAE is B/2. Therefore <DAB=E, hence AD is parallel to BC (because the angles <DAB and <ABC=B sum to 180°) at which point the whole edifice comes crashing down. Indeed, it follows E=B=C=90° and A=D=135° which is incompatible with the pentagon being equilateral.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Thanks! +1

Comment: Your second spoiler is rather hard to follow. Two questions - how do you know rot13(gur gevnatyr vf vfbfpryrf), and rot13(jul qbrf gung znxr gur yvar cnenyyry)? I think it would be much easier to understand if you included those intermediate steps.

Comment: Done, @RobWatts. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: This is pretty much the same proof as mine, which can be found in [this pdf](https://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/g4g11paper.pdf) together with two other geometry problems from tilings.

Comment: Is there any picture where we can see the different tiles being overlapped on top of each other to see the discrepancies?

Comment: @justhalf If I remember correctly, on my tile BC and AD were parallel, so side b was a bit longer than the other sides. In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luJO3.png) you can see 6 tiles forming the fundamental unit for the tiling, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqYVA.png) it is repeated without the colours so the overlap is very noticeable.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Would it be possible to generate "optimal" tiles by minimizing some penalty function perhaps using your code which you mentioned somewhere?

Comment: That sounds like a perfectly feasible thing to do, just not with my code. My code consists of tiling search programs which did not find this tile for obvious reasons, and a tiling viewer which you can find on my site [here](https://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/). However, to just make a goodlooking tiling I would probably use three slightly differing tiles that looked identical rather than trying to get a single tile to almost work. (fixed link)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Argh, those animated gifs have given me a dizzy spell!

Comment: How does [Livio Zucca's example](https://www.iread.it/lz/pagesp/nc180h.html) fail? Using your point-labelling, & his angles (B=103.644, A=129.486, E=76.356, D=140.514, C=90) we can place the points B=(0,1), C=(0,0), D=(1,0), A=(.97178,1.23589), E=(1.77178, .63589). Indeed AE=1 near enough, & DAE=EDA=CBA/2. But BAD=77.664 & ADC=88.692, not 90.

Comment: @RosieF It satisfies most contraints but not 360 = A+A+B = E+D+D. In fact 2A+B=362.616 and 2D+E=357.384 so at some vertices in the tiling the angles don't add up to 360.